# Sounds cut off early on some phones

Tags: android, audio

I'm the developer of a Soundboard app. A lot of users have reported me that in their phones some of the sounds cut off early. I have a Nexus One and a HTC Tattoo and everything works fine, I've never noticed the cut off in my phones.

This is my code for the audio part:

First, I have a MediaPlayer object in my main class:

```
private MediaPlayer mp = null;
```

And when I puss a button, this is the code:

```
    private OnClickListener onClickSound = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mp != null){
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), mp3id));
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);
    }
};
```

And this is the completionListener:

```
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaP) {
        if(mp != null && !mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }

};
```

You guys have any clue?

Greetings

Comment: You could try to narrow down the problem by finding out on which phone models / OS versions this problem occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You're starting playing before player loads all the media. Use setOnPreparedListener to start only after player is ready.

Comment: Can you update question with setOnPreparedListener code which doesn't work?

Comment: The docs state that `create` is synchronized, so the player should be ready to `play()` right after, in contrast to using `new`.